# How to find the supremum of this?

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to know how to find this supremum
$$ \sup_{x \in [1,\infty)} \left| n\left( \sqrt{x+\frac{1}{n}}-\sqrt{x} \right) - \frac{1}{2\cdot \sqrt{x}} \right|=?$$ where $ n \in \mathbb{N} $.

I suppose that we can find it by investigating monotonicity (1st derivation, stationary points, find a maximum). But this process is very time-consuming.

Are there any different ways how to solve it? I have no idea how to estimate the value of this supremum.

Comment: What happens when $x\to 0^+$? Are you sure the $\sup$ is taken over all of $\mathbb{R}^+$?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. This example is from my textbook.

Comment: When I see a question like this, I will plot it out and try to get a feel what happens. For this problem, the answer is obvious once you look at the plot.

Comment: @Anakin Then answer my first question to get the answer.

Comment: Oh sorry I have made a mistake. I am very sorry for that. You are right. This sup is taken just over [1,infinity) but still I dont know how to estimate it.

Comment: Ah, dans ce cas là, I think some computation is necessary.

Comment: I think that the value of sup is maximal for x=1 but I am not sure. Does anybody else think its a good idea?

Comment: The sup is maximal at $x=1$. To prove it, transform your function to something obviously monotonic using algebraic identity $$n\left(\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{n}}-\sqrt{x}\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{n}} + \sqrt{x}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Following the hint given by achille hui: rewrite the difference as
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{n}}+\sqrt{x}} - \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} = 
\frac{\sqrt{x}- \sqrt{x+\frac{1}{n}} }{2\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{n}}+\sqrt{x})} $$
and then as
$$\frac{-1/n}{2\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{n}}+\sqrt{x})^2} $$ at which point the monotonicity becomes clear.